# Where i should write gradle init command

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

I want to converte my Maven project to Gradle.
In official Gradle docs is written "**All you have to do is run the command 
'$ gradle init'
from the root project directory and let Gradle do its thing.**",but I can't understand one thing - where exactly in the root project directory i should write this init command.

---

I tried to cd into the project directory in Windows Terminal and after this run init gradle but it doesn't work.

[image: 1Photo]

This is my project directory[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: As documentation says: the `gradle init` command should be executed from the maven project root dir (where the `pom.xml` file resides):  what is the output when you execute the command? can you try with debug flag `gradle init -d` ?

Comment: When i input **gradle init** in Windows Terminal it writes me **gradle is not internal or external command, executable program or batch file.** Same with **gradle init -d**

Comment: did you install Gradle? it does not seem so. or maybe your PATH variable does not reference the Gradle  `bin` dir properly.

Comment: Yes,i installed Gradle, but in another path 'C:\Gradle\gradle-4.10.2'.And what the PATH variable?

Comment: if you type `gradle -v` from any location: does it print something ? because your errer message `gradle is not internal or external command, executable program or batch file` means your Gradle executable is not in PATH

Comment: It prints the same error.And  in what PATH i must put gradle?

Comment: ==> https://gradle.org/install/#manually   , see step 3

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thanks a lot.Finally got it.